# Random button for method

Tags: android, button, random

I have two buttons (bt1, bt2).

**I need :** If you click on `button`, it will redirect you to another `Activity`, but when you press the second, it redirects you to the previous `Activity`. But these two methods have to alternate (random) between the two `buttons`. What should I write?

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `onClickListener()` to both buttons, in which you randomly do either one or the other.

```
OnClickListener listener = (new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    //On click function
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Random random = new Random();
        if(random.nextBoolean()){
            //do one thing here
        } else {
            //do the other thing here
        }
    }
});
bt1.setOnClickListener(listener)
bt2.setOnClickListener(listener)
```

Now, your buttons behavior is random. However, I have no Idea why you want ***2*** buttons for this.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Button click and go to the next Activity :

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickButton);
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Go to the next Activity
                }
            });
```

for going back you can use `setOnLongClickListener`:

```
 button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

For going Back :

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```